# Converting a javascript .millis() object into its python equivalent

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

I have the following functional code in javascript:

```
Date(0).update(2020,1,1,12,0,0).millis()
```

I have been trying to get it working in python. But I must be doing something very wrong.

```
import time
time_tuple = time.strptime('2020-1-1 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time_epoch = time.mktime(time_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
dt_obj = datetime.strptime('2020-1-1 12:00:00',
                           '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000
```

Here is the explanation of the format specifiers from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: your solution works! but somehow I am off by 3 hours from what I was expecting. There must be some timezone problem still hidden somewhere.

Comment: make sure the timezone is in the string. Python might have the default timezone set in global different from what you expect. So I suggest as a rule of thumb to always keep the timezone with the time. So now your string should be something like: +0400 at the end and then have %z in the format